# I'm trying to get jquery working in the background.js of my chrome extension and it won't work. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've read up on quite a few stack overflow questions about jQuery and background pages and simply do not understand the rules of engagement.  I don't know how they interact.  Can somebody tell me why this code does not work?

```
manifest.json

{
  "name": "test 1",
  "description": "testing jquery",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "jquery-2.1.1.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
     "default_title": "test"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

i don't forget to include the jQuery file when i upload the extension

```
background.js

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    { code: 'console.log("this works");'},
    { code: '$( document ).ready(function() { console.log( "but this does not work :(" ); });' }
  );
});
```

keep in mind i'm familiar with how to use jQuery using content scripts but the problem with these is then the

```
chrome.******
```

commands don't work.

Please help!

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript` will execute code in the context of the webpage. So you need to inject jQuery into the webpage in the first place (or use the existing jQuery if available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly loading jQuery into the background page. If you were to use `$(document).ready()` in its code, it would work.

The problem is, when you use `executeScript`, the code you specify does not execute in the same context as `background.js`. A brand new JS context is created, attached to the tab in question, and that context does not have jQuery in it (even if the tab's context itself has it, by the way, see [isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)).

Furthermore, you're calling [`executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) wrong. Its arguments are:

- integer   (optional) `tabId`
- object    `details`
- function  (optional) `callback`

You are calling it with two objects; it doesn't work like that.

---

So, to fix, you will need to inject jQuery first in that execution context, and then your code. You need to chain 2 calls to ensure they execute in the correct order.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id,
    { file: 'jquery-2.1.1.js' },
    function() {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tab.id,
        { code: '$( document ).ready(function() { console.log( "This works now" ); });' }
      );
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I meant, jQuery should work in background page itself (but that's not what you wanted)